# Resizing images using Fresco library in Java

Tags: android, image-resizing, fresco

I'm using Fresco library by Facebook to load and show image from URL.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(image_url);
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

How can I resize this image in java?

Comment: https://frescolib.org/docs/resizing.html

Answer (score 0):

reading the `Fresco` Documentation, I've found this:

> #### Resizing
>
> Resizing does not modify the original file. Resizing just resizes an encoded image in memory, prior to being decoded.
>
> To resize pass a ResizeOptions object when constructing an
>   ImageRequest:
>
> ```
> Uri uri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/MyApp/myfile.jpg";
> int width = 50, height = 50;
> ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
>     .setResizeOptions(new ResizeOptions(width, height))
>     .build();
> PipelineDraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
>     .setOldController(mDraweeView.getController())
>     .setImageRequest(request)
>     .build();
> mSimpleDraweeView.setController(controller);
> ```
>
> Resizing has some limitations:
>
> - it only supports JPEG files
> - the actual resize is carried out to the nearest 1/8 of the original size
> - it cannot make your image bigger, only smaller (not a real limitation though)

If you have any question, please free to ask

Hope it help